# Conversion/mapping method best practice

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Let's say there are two C++ classes CDataProvider and CDbWrapper as follows:

```
Class CDataProvider {
public:
    void setData(MyDataType);
    void getData(MyDataType&);
    // ... snip ...
private:
   MyDataType d; // cached data
   CDbWrapper db;
   convertMyTypeToMyDbType(MyDataType, MyDbDataType&);
   convertMyDbTypeToMyType(MyDbDataType, MyDataType&);

};

Class CDbWrapper {
public:
    bool getFromDb(MyDbDataType&); 
    bool setToDb(MyDbDataType);
    // ... snip ...
};
```

In `CDataProvider::setData` we would be first converting the data to the format understood by the db and storing it.

My question is whether it makes sense for the convert methods to exist as such in the data provider to be able to decouple the two classes and not have to share the same types. Please be aware that in reality, there is more complexity in the data and so sharing data types in headers between the classes in not clean.

Comment: Just write the code the way that feels most natural. Think (as you are clearly doing) on the impact possible/probable extensions will have on your design. On a cursory look it seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Already known solution**

By looking at already existent design patterns listings (eg: wikipedia) there isn't anything directly related to this problem. In this situation the best solution would be try to use an already known design pattern to tackle the problem.

*Wrapper*

Adapter/Wrapper pattern could provide a good solution to this question. Here the different types are just wrapping the original types.

**Other solutions**

Copy and paste? **:)**